# Qt C++ Stand alone executable in Windows

Tags: c++, qt

I want to make my Qt C++ program a stand alone single application. By the way, I am using Qt creator 2.2.1 which is based on Qt 4.7.4. I followed the instructions from http://www.formortals.com/how-to-statically-link-qt-4/ to statically link the libraries. I did not know where to find the configure.exe in the QtSDK folder so I downloaded "qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3" and followed the instructions.

I was unsure in Step 4 because the windows Qt options do not look similar. Its not a path to a folder but rather a path to qmake location and I am not sure what to choose for that option.

If anyone knows how to create the program as a stand alone without needing any dlls and can help me out, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: The Qt library comes by default as a DLL. Do you really want "without any dll's" or do you just want to create a working application?

Comment: @Jay when i mean no dll's I mean that they be included in the executable. So the exe has everything it needs to run without any external files. So another user in a different computer does not need to install Qt to be able to run the program

Comment: @Jay: Probably what's he's asking for, is no DLLs that don't come with the OS.

Comment: @user844778: You _are_ aware that the Open Source version of QT comes under the (L)GPL? I.e. you'll have to abide by those terms. This generally means you can't distribute just the EXE; you'll also have to distribute the license terms.

Comment: @MSalters, Where do I find the license terms?

Comment: @user844778: http://qt.nokia.com/products/licensing/

Comment: Updated licensing link: https://qt-project.org/products/licensing

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the *step 4* you mentioned, in `QtCreator` you need to point the `qmake` executable you will find it in the build tree (where you built Qt statically) in the `bin` folder.

I guess if you have problems on *step 4* you should have built the static version of `Qt`, you've done 95% of the work !

The moment `QtCreator` will accept the `qmake` you *made*, you will just have to select this version use any wizard to get you first app, then add `CONFIG += static` to you `.pro` file.

[Here](https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows) some Qt tutorial just in case.

Comment: Note that Qt is LGPL (unless you have a commercial licence) so if you statically link your app it becomes GPL (actually not quite, if you want to do a lot of work to allow relinking)

Comment: @vrince, I followed the steps in the tutorial and I am running into a fatal error when I reached the 'nmake release'. The error is: "'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command, or batch file." Have any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to configure qmake with the msvc spec file (to use the Microsoft toolchain (compiler)). Try to reconfigure with -spec=msvc-.... Then run the nmake (or jom) in a visual studio command shell (you need to install a free version of visual to have it ...)

Comment: @vrince, i ran "configure -static -release -platform win32-msvc2010" and then "nmake sub-src" in visual studio command promt 2010 is that what you are referring to? I get same error when I run "nmake release"

Comment: @user844778: Yeah that's what I meant but if you get a 'gcc error' after that I don't know why ... [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC) a more complete blog about building Qt on windows (see static part of it)

Comment: @vrince, I found out that static build in QT SDK 4.7.3 needs a patch for static building. I just realized that I am getting the same error in wingw32-make as the person in http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/7644 Do you know where to place the patch file mentioned in the article?